# using __name__ inside input element

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade template with input html tags and the name attribute written in this way  `__name__` , what it is used for and what's the difference if i use the name attribute instead

example:

```
<input type="text" __name__="extra_price[__number__][name{{$key}}]" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="{{__('Extra price name')}}">
```